# Для программы определено несколько точек входа

Tags: c#

Для программы определено несколько точек входа. Компиляция с /main позволит указать тип содержащий точку входа

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Size = new Size(600, 600);
            this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Form1_Paint);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            int centerX = this.ClientSize.Width / 2;
            int centerY = this.ClientSize.Height / 2;
            int radius = this.ClientSize.Width / 4;
    
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, centerX - radius, centerY - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
                radius += 20;
            }
        }
    
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос или проблема?

Comment: ух... что вы пытаетесь сделать? Для чего вам `Main` внутри `Form1`? В классическом WinForms-приложении `Main` расположен в классе `Program` в файле Program.cs и он, по-умолчанию, итак вызывает `Form1`. Уберите `Main` из `Form1`

Comment: спасибо за помощь!

Comment: не могли бы пожалуста написать как должен выглядет код?